# Most useful free SharePoint 2010 Utilities/libraries?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Kindly provide all free Utilities/libraries details here so that we can make a one stop shop for users to find free utilities
Mine contribution

[mixed authentication](http://spautomaticsignin.codeplex.com/)

[SharePoint AJAX Toolkit for SharePoint 2010](http://sharepointajax.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft Patterns & Practices - SharePoint Guidance](http://spg.codeplex.com/)

- [SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798371.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint 2010 Service Manager](http://sharepointserviceman.codeplex.com/) - Easily turn SharePoint services on/off on your dev box.

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) : A visual representation of the SharePoint object model that lets you interact with lists, webs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) for SharePoint 2003 and SharePoint 2007. Its a worth have for SharePoint geeks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

All the tools and functionalities that are available within the essential CKS:DEV Visual Studio 2010 extension http://cksdev.codeplex.com/ are absolutely essential for anyone developing any code related solutions in SharePoint 2010.

I'm also a big fan of the Starter Master Pages http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/ which helped me a lot when I had to create my first 2010 project.

For rapid virtual environment creation, I do like the scripts available within the Auto SharePoint Installer http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/

Finally, don't forget that SharePoint Designer 2010 is free like it's little brother, and unlike the awful mess that was the previous edition, this new release is much more stable and less clumsy (It's still not something I would easily recommand but it helps to get some things done when you know what you are doing).